# Formatting a type's name

Tags: c#, .net, formatting, .net-core

I'm writing a code generation library, I've exposed a couple of methods and of course in order to define a member you need to specify it's type, the easiest way is to use `typeof(Type)`, which I later format so that it it's compilable and I can insert it as a code chunk e.g. `System.Int32`, which for non-generic types is basically concatenating the namespace and the type's name.

That works fine but generic types have the backtick followed by the number of arguments, so I needed a method to format all the types, so that they are always compilable e.g. `System.Collection.Generics.List<System.Int32>`.

```
public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static string FormatTypeName(this Type type)
    {
        if(type == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type)); }

        if (type.IsGenericType)
        {
            var definedArguments = type.GetGenericArguments();
            var genericIdentifier = $"`{definedArguments.Length}";

            if (definedArguments.First().FullName == null)
            {
                var genericBraces = "<".PadRight(definedArguments.Length, ',') + ">";
                return $"{type.Namespace}.{type.Name.Replace(genericIdentifier, genericBraces)}";
            }

            var formattedTypes = definedArguments.Select(definedArgument => definedArgument.FormatTypeName());

            var newGenericArguments = $"<{string.Join(", ", formattedTypes)}>";
            return $"{type.Namespace}.{type.Name.Replace(genericIdentifier, newGenericArguments, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)}";
        }

        return $"{type.Namespace}.{type.Name}";
    }
}
```

It supports indefinite amount of nested and linear generic arguments due to the recursion that is in-place.

---

The way it works is pretty straight forward, there are 2 possible incomes, we have no arguments defined e.g. `typeof(Dictionary<,>)` or all of the arguments are defined e.g `typeof(Dictionary<int, int>)`.

Since the C# compiler doesn't allow partially defined arguments we can simply check if the first of the arguments has a FullName (note that `Name` is the name pf the generic argument not the type behind it), if it does we simply concatenate all of the arguments and surround them by `<>`. if the first argument doesn't have value then it's empty and we just leave the braces with commas separating the arguments.

---

Since this will be used in a code generation tool, performance is not crucial, but always welcome as long as it doesn't damage the readability and maintainability of the code, which I consider more important in this case.

However since it will be used in a code generation tool, I'm more worried about whether I've missed some edge cases.

Comment: Since FormatTypeName is an extension method I don't think that the parameter type can ever be null. Also, if you want more performance you can take a look at this answer for how to create strings of repeated characters. https://stackoverflow.com/a/720915/7412948

Comment: @JeffreyParks It can be null! :)

Comment: Good to know! Also, if this proves to be too slow and you have a lot of repeated type usage, you could consider caching the results into a static Dictionary<type,string> so you avoid a lot of repeated work.

Comment: @JeffreyParks an extension method is just syntax sugar for `ExtClass.ExtMethod(obj)`, it's not a member call on `obj` ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can let `CSharpCodeProvider` format Type names:

```
public static string FormatTypeName(this Type type)
{
    using (var c = new CSharpCodeProvider()) {
        var r = new CodeTypeReference(type);
        return c.GetTypeOutput(r);
    }
}
```